# Can not resolve symbol on calendar write permission request

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to get the users permission in android to write and read to the calendar. However I get an error on the following code:

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR  },
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CALENDAR);
    }
```

It says: can not resolve symbol MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CALENDAR.
I can't quite figure out what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250418/call-requires-permission-for-content-uri-in-calender) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html):

> requestPermissions(Activity activity, String[] permissions, int requestCode)
>
> requestCode   int: Application specific request code to match with a result reported to onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]).

So this last parameter is just a requestCode (int) of your choice. It's good practice to declare this as a final int in your class.